# How to make an existing column autoincrement in Oracle

Tags: oracle-12c, auto-increment

I have created a table in oracle database which I named `USERS` and I have created a column `USER_ID` with type `NUMBER` which i set as primary key.

How can I modify  the column `USER_ID` to make it auto increment by 1 ?

Any help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using IDENTITY, it is not be possible  - you cannot modify non-identity column to identity.  However,  Oracle lets you use sequence.nextval as default, so you may get similar functionality  :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USER START WITH 1000; --assuming max(USERS.user_id) =999
ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY (USER_ID DEFAULT SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL);
```

It will work as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible.

[ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ALTER-TABLE.htm)

> **identity_clause**
>
> Use identity_clause to modify the properties of an identity column.
>   You cannot specify this clause on a column that is not an identity
>   column.